# Running 2 python scripts with dependencies

Tags: python, python-import

I have 3 python scripts which I am trying to run as a final script but I am unable to transfer the variables over. I have script_A.py with all the data.

script_B.py and script_C.py uses all the variables from script A. So "from script_A import *" works on each.

I want to run both script_B.py and script_C.py in a final script, final_script.py
How may I do that without having to initialize variables in script_A.py twice in my final_script.py?

Comment: Script B & C should contain only functions, without importing script A. To debug, you can add a if ____name__=="__main____": at the end of B &C where you import the variables from A and do your testing. In your final script, simply import the functions from B&C and the variables from A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to `script_A`'s variables using `script_B` and `script_C` respectively.

Here's a demonstration:

`A.py`

```
foo = 5
print('In A')
```

`B.py`

```
from A import *
print('In B')
```

`final.py`

```
import B
print('In final')
print B.foo
```

Now, running `final.py` gives:

```
In A
In B
In final
5
```

As you can see, once `B` imports `A`'s data, it becomes a part of B, so other classes that `import B` can refer to `A`'s data through `B` directly without having to import `A` again.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the `script_B.py` and `script_C.py` files to be separately executable scripts, my solution would be to refactor the scripts to contain functions that take all the relavant variables as arguments:

`script_A.py`:

```
var1 = 'foo'
var2 = 'bar'
```

`script_B.py`

```
def do_b(var1, var2):
    pass    # do things with var1 and var2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from script_A import var1, var2
    do_b(var1=var1, var2=var2)
```

`script_C.py`

```
def do_c(var1, var2):
    pass    # do things with var1 and var2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from script_A import var1, var2
    do_c(var1=var1, var2=var2)
```

`final_script.py`

```
from script_A import var1, var2
from script_B import do_b
from script_C import do_c


def main():
    do_b(var1, var2)
    do_c(var1, var2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This works as well! But rendering all of my variables from A into one function in script B and C is quite cumbersome.